# Accessing Instance of a class from IntentService Class

Tags: android

I am new to Android and here i am stuck at a point . 
There is a class (say class_A) , MainActivity and a Service class(which extends IntentService)
I have an instance of Class_A in my MainActivity which gets updated with user's response . I want to use the same instance in my Service class , so that on the basis of updated instance of Class_A i can perform task present in my Service Class (the service runs indefinitely) .

Any kind of help is appreciated . Or if the above approach is wrong please do suggest other methods of doing it .

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking. What you're probably looking for is a Singleton (which some people consider evil) or shared preferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html